# Libgdx Actor Text

Tags: java, libgdx

currently I am in the process of developing a trading card game in Java using Libgdx. Each player has a number of cards with different abilities and attributes. Each card class extends the Actor class, but I am wondering if there is a way I can draw text onto these Actors, that will move when the cards do.

For example, each card has a set amount of hit points, which will vary depending on the damage that card has taken. I was wondering what the best way to draw these hitpoints into the card would be, so that when the card moves, the hitpoints will move with it. Occasionally, the cards will stack or overlap, and in these instances I would obviously want the text of cards at the bottom to be concealed by cards at the top, rather than it all overlapping.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy solution thanks to the inheritance that libGDX provides.

As `Group` is an actor you can easily do... (pseudo code)

```
public class Card extends Group {

  final private static TextureAtlas ATLAS;

  static {

    ATLAS = AssetManager.get("game.pack", TextureAtlas.class);
  }

  public enum Type {

    type1, type2, type3
  }

  private Type type;
  private Image card;
  private Label text;
  private int hitPoints;

  public Card(Type type) {

    this.type = type;

    card = new Image(ATLAS.get(type));
    text = new Label("HP: " + hitPoints);

    addActor(card);
    addActor(text);
  }
}
```

This assumes you have enum for card types associated with the identifiers in your texture atlas; if you are not using a texture atlas I highly recommend that you do.

In your game logic class I am assuming it would be an extension of the `Screen` class you can simply;

```
private Card card;

@override
public void show() {

  card = new Card(Card.Type.type1);
  stage.addActor(card);

  // This is an example - as the card and text reside within a group they can be moved as a sole entity relative to their parent
  card.addAction(moveBy(100, 100, 2, Interpolation.Linear));
}
```

Of course positioning of actors if specific to your use case etc... Any questions just ask :)